# Yum cannot find the package I want to install

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I am trying to a simple command `sudo yum install SDL2`. I know that this package exists as per the SDL website:

> Red Hat-based systems (including Fedora) can simply do "sudo yum install SDL2" to get the library installed system-wide, or "sudo yum install SDL2-devel" to get headers and other build requirements ready for compiling your own SDL programs.

However, when I try to execute my command, I get the following:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package SDL2 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga). How can I go about getting yum to locate this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ONLY SDL is available on redhat 5.3

```
uname -r
2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64

yum search sdl-devel --verbose
SDL-devel.x86_64 : Files needed to develop Simple DirectMedia Layer   applications
Repo        : base
```

With Fedora 26, SDL2 is available in repo fedora

```
uname -r
4.11.0-2.fc26.x86_64
dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="fedora" search sdl2-devel --verbose

SDL2-devel.x86_64 : Files needed to develop Simple DirectMedia Layer applications
Repo        : fedora
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way around this limitation. Maybe there is some way I could build from source?

Comment: build from source rpm might be OK in  EL7, unlikely to succeed in EL5, best bet is to build from source.tar.gz http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/SDL2.git/commit/?h=epel7[http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/SDL2.git/commit/?h=epel7]